# As a student, how can I improve poor code?

Tags: c++, optimization

How do I improve this spaghetti code? I am a student and this is me being slow in my first programming course.

**What I think I want to achieve**

Find an alternating sum up to a number.

**Problem overview**

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/cs102-s18-march31/challenges/treasure-road

This is a problem from the archive at provided by the teacher. I have deduced that an alternating sum has to be calculated, where the sum of the first *odd integers* has to be subtracted from the sum of the first *even integers* (of course up to #ofsteps/2).

**What I did**

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int arrodds[100]={0},arrevens[100]={0},sumevens=0,sumodds=0;
    int steps;
    cin >> steps;
    int i=0;
    while(i<steps/2)
    {
        if(i%2==0)
            arrevens[i]=i;
        else arrodds[i]=i;
        i++;
    }
    for(int d=0;d<100;d++)
        sumevens+=arrevens[d];
    for(int h=0;h<100;h++)
        sumodds+=arrodds[h];

    cout << sumodds-sumevens;
    return 0;
}
```

**My logic/reasoning**

Zingo can only move Steps/2, if he moves an odd step he moves forward, and Ringo moves a step closer to to Zingo, else if Zingo moves an even step Ringo moves away from Zingo.

Let's say there are 10 steps... 10/5=5... 5 steps= 1+2+3+4+5, odd steps=1,3,5; even steps=2,4; so displacement is 1+3-(2+4)=-2.

**The code**

I try to store the even and odd numbers in different arrays, then take the sum of each one and subtract the sums.

**What's wrong?**

My code works for small numbers it seems, as some test cases go beyond what I think My code could handle.

**What I tried**

I tried playing around with the sizes of my arrays but didn't get what I want.

Should I abandon this code and try something else? If not, how can I fix this abomination and guide me through it?

Comment: You could find a math series or integral or formula for finding the sum of odd numbers and implement that.

Comment: Another idea is to implement a *running sum* and not use an array.

Comment: You may want to assign `steps/2` to a constant temporary variable, so that it is not calculated in each iteration (although a good compiler could optimize that).

Comment: You should be using `steps` instead of `100` in your summing loops.

Comment: Spend more time proofreading: adivce -> advice.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! There’s also another site for questions about how to improve a program, https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a running sum instead of using arrays:

```
sum_evens = 0;
sum_odds  = 0; 
for (int i = 0; i < steps; ++i)
{
  if (i & 1)
  {
    sum_odds += i;
  }
  else
  {
    sum_evens += i;
  }
}
```

**Edit 1:**
The sum of the first `N` odd numbers is `N*N`.
You could change the calculation to:

```
sum_odds = steps * steps;
```

I'll leave the calculation of the first `N` even numbers up to the reader / OP.